# Intervent whilst hibernate materialization of entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to intervent the construction of hibernate entities from a result set?
For example:
I have an entity `Reference` with a property of `referenceType`.
I want to add a transient property called `referenceSpecialType` based on the value of `referenceType`.

My idea is that this has to be done whilst hibernate's materialization of entities, so that i don´t have to `foreach` all entities after materialization.

Furthermore would it be cool to use a `Bean` from spring to do the job of the `referenceSpecialType` building.

Pseudocode:

```
class customRowMapper(JdbcResultSet resultSet){
this.reference = new Reference(resultSet):
this.autowiredSpringBean.transformSpecialType(this.reference.referenceType);
}
```

Please note:
I need a way to do this logic whilst hibernate instantiates this types - not after.

Comment: Maybe [JPA Callbacks](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks) are what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds cool. I will give it a try.